Custom Directives outputs error for a tooltip component in a vue3 application styled with Tailwind
I am trying to make a ToolTip directive. When I hover over my tooltip component I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: instance.showTooltip is not a function
    show tooltip.js:20
    mounted tooltip.js:26
    callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:195
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:202
    invokeDirectiveHook runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2105
    mountElement runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5550
    flushPostFlushCbs runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:370
    flushJobs runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:408
    promise callback*queueFlush runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:311
    queueJob runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:305
    scheduler runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1968
    resetScheduling reactivity.esm-bundler.js:264
    trigger reactivity.esm-bundler.js:404
    set reactivity.esm-bundler.js:525
    set value reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1191
    set reactivity.esm-bundler.js:514
    set pinia.mjs:929
    searchTracks tracks.js:30
    wrapAction pinia.mjs:1380
    actionName pinia.mjs:935
    fetchTracks requests.js:12
    setup Hero.vue:55
    createHook runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2865
    callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:195
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:202
    __weh runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2845
    flushPostFlushCbs runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:370
    render2 runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6669
    mount runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3921
    mount runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1511
    <anonymous> main.js:37
    promise callback* main.js:32

It looks like the way the showTooltip and hideTooltip function are exposed from the ToolTip definition isn't really working.
Here is the ToolTip component:
<template>
    <div v-if="visible" :class="tooltipClasses" :style="style">
        {{ text }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, defineExpose } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    position: {
        type: String,
        default: 'top'
    }
})

const visible = ref(true)
const style = ref({})

const showTooltip = (event) => {
    visible.value = true
    const { top, left, width, height } = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    const tooltipHeight = 30 // Approximate height of the tooltip

    switch (props.position) {
        case 'top':
            style.value = {
                left: `${left + width / 2}px`,
                top: `${top - tooltipHeight}px`,
                transform: 'translateX(-50%)'
            }
            break
        case 'bottom':
            style.value = {
                left: `${left + width / 2}px`,
                top: `${top + height + tooltipHeight}px`,
                transform: 'translateX(-50%)'
            }
            break
        case 'left':
            style.value = {
                left: `${left - tooltipHeight}px`,
                top: `${top + height / 2}px`,
                transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
            }
            break
        case 'right':
            style.value = {
                left: `${left + width + tooltipHeight}px`,
                top: `${top + height / 2}px`,
                transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
            }
            break
    }
}

const hideTooltip = () => {
    visible.value = false
}

// Expose the methods so they can be called from outside
defineExpose({
    showTooltip,
    hideTooltip
})

const tooltipClasses = ref("absolute top-2 left-2 bg-black text-white text-sm px-2 py-1 rounded shadow-lg pointer-events-none z-50")
</script>

<style scoped>
.tooltip {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
</style>

Here is the directive definition:
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import Tooltip from '@/components/Tooltip.vue'

const TooltipDirective = {
  mounted(el, binding) {
    const app = createApp({
      render() {
        return h(Tooltip, {
          text: binding.value,
          position: binding.arg || 'top'
        })
      }
    })
    const instance = app.mount(document.createElement('div'))
    document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)

        const show = (event) => {
      instance.showTooltip(event)
    }
    const hide = () => {
      instance.hideTooltip()
    }

    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', show)
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', hide)

    el._tooltip = {
      instance,
      show,
      hide
    }
  },
  unmounted(el) {
    const { instance, show, hide } = el._tooltip
    el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', show)
    el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', hide)
    document.body.removeChild(instance.$el)
  }
}

export default TooltipDirective


This is the ToolTip in use:
<div v-tooltip="'This is a tooltip kragh'" class="relative bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded">
  Hover me !!
</div>

